# How to add button in the bottom of recyclerview in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am new to constraint layout and I am trying to add my button below recyclerview, but I am not able to do that in constraint layout.
How I can achieve this functionality in constraint layout.

[I am also share image for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B7WL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The important point is that the `ListView`'s height must be **0** and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` .

Comment: One more thing is there any proper documentation for constraint layout properties because I want to know which property is for what and how will you use that property.

Comment: Yes take a look at Google's documentation:     https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```